# How to make optional capturing groups be matched first

Tags: regex

For example I want to match three values, required `text`, optional `times` and `id`, and the format of `id` is `[id=100000]`, how can I match data correctly when `text` contains spaces.

```
my reg: (?<text>[\s\S]+) (?<times>\d+)? (\[id=(?<id>\d+)])?

example source text: hello world 1 [id=10000]
```

In this example, all of source text are matched in `text`

Comment: the idea is that the capturing group 'text' contains 'hello word' , 'times' contain '1' and 'id' contain the '10000' right?, also do you have some strings to test or which language are you using?

Comment: @lucas_7_94 yes

Comment: Confirm if this suits for you: https://regex101.com/r/rsfEm8/1 else put a list of string or more examples for further examination

Comment: That's cool, but can it be implemented if it has numbers in `text`?

Comment: how would you differentiate between a number in `text` and a number that represents the `times`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your pattern is that matches any whitespace and non whitespace one and unlimited times, which captures everything without getting the other desired capture groups. Also, with a little help with the positive lookahead and alternate (`|`) , we can make the last 2 capture groups desired optional.

The final pattern `(?<text>[a-zA-Z ]+)(?=$|(?<times>\d+)? \[id=(?<id>\d+)])`

- Group text will match any letter and spaces.
- The lookahead avoid consuming characters and we should match either the string ended, or have a number and [id=number]

Said that, [regex101 with further explanation and some examples](https://regex101.com/r/euEUtA/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
:\s*(?<text>[^][:]+?)\s*(?<times>\d+)? \[id=(?<id>\d+)]
```

**Explanation**

- `:` Match literally
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?<text>` Group *text*

  - `[^][:]+?` match 1+ occurrences of any char except `[` `]` `:`
- `)` Close group text
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(?<times>\d+)?` Group *times*, match 1+ digits
- `\[id=` Match `[id=`
- `(?<id>\d+)` Group *id*, match 1+ digirs
- `]` Match literally

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/O76OvP/1)